# O que fazer? Safari IOS não mostra elementos dentro de Dialog gerado por jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, mobile-safari

Bom dia.

Introdução:
Tenho um site em produção utilizando jQuery UI faz um bom tempo. Excetuando o problema que apresento, todos os dialogs mostram tudo no Safari IOS.

O problema:
Desenvolvi um novo relatório onde o usuário pode escolher, por checkbox um ou mais do mesmo parâmetro.

Funciona perfeitamente no Chrome e Firefox, mas no Safari IOS ele abre os dialogs, mas não mostra os checkbox. Os checkbox estão lá, pois eu coloquei um um botão para marcar todos e ele faz o programado, caso um ou mais seja marcado, ao fechar o dialog.

Contestação provável:
Se dá certo no Chrome e Firefox, por que não os usa? Resposta: a opção de salvar uma página em PDF é nativa apenas do Safari IOS e não achei uma solução para imprimir em PDF pelo Chrome e Firefox (a não ser sugerir que ele troque o iPhone dele pelo meu Android, *risos*).

O que tentei a mais:
Procurei em fóruns em inglês e português, mas nada fez o Safari mostrar os elementos.

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado!

Ativei tudo o que havia nas features do Safari IOS relacionadas a CSS e limpei o histórico e cache.